# What jQuery script do I need to link in my html page in order for the following code to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to get this to work in a standalone HTML file: http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/2/

My script is:

```
var divs = $('.fademe');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/130) });
});
```

I've tried these includes, but none of them work:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
It is wrapped. The script in my HTML is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $('.fademe');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/700) });
});
</script>
```

And it works in jsFiddle, but **not** when I try and view it as it's own HTML page

Comment: It is working for me - the box fades away correctly in your fiddle.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome v25 on Mac, it appears to be working. Meanwhile, in your recent edit, you did not close the function correctly - it is easier to spot mistakes if you indent your code properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.on()` function was added in jQuery 1.7, and the `.css()` function was added in jQuery 1.0, so any of those three files will contain all of the necessary functions; the first two are the same file, one has just been compressed (minified - hence the ".min" part of the filename).

However, your code is likely executing too early - before the DOM has been constructed - so the elements can't be selected. Delay the execution of that code using a `DOM ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing divs incorrectly.
If you're going to be applying a jquery function to a variable that you've selected, you have to do it like this.

```
$(divs).css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/130) });
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. He is accessing the divs correctly, because he has defined the variable `divs` as a jQuery object already: `var divs = $('.fademe');`